# gradle shortened property explanation

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, groovy, android-gradle-plugin

I was digging into gradle scripting and I figured out that `project.ext` and `project.extensions.extraProperties` are the same object.

I wonder:

- Why there are two ways to acces this particular object?
- Why `project.extensions.extraProperties` is recognized by IntelliJ Idea and `project.ext` is not

---

```
project.ext.myprop = 3
project.extensions.extraProperties.myprop = 4
println project.ext.myprop // print 4
```

Comment: Please check this article for some tips: https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.ExtraPropertiesExtension.html. What do you mean by "project.ext is not recognized by IntelliJ Idea"?

Comment: @y.bedrov Thanks for the link. The auto-completion and Syntax highlighting aren't working on `project.ext`. As reference : `project.ext.each { it }` the `it` is unknown. The type `ExtraPropertiesExtension` seems to not be recognized.

Comment: @LionelBriand, what does your title "shrink name explanation" mean?

Comment: @chenrui I have edited the question title, Hope it was more meaningful.

Comment: Looks like a bug. Please report new issue on YouTrack: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA.